# CentOS 6.5 Bridged Networking Fails

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, linux-networking, bridge

I have a CentOS 6.5 Server that I wish to host VPS on, as well as installing SolusVM, to do this I need to bridge the network adapters for the Server and the VM's ( so the VM's can connect to the internet) The two adapters are eth0 (the server adapter located at /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0) and virbr0 for the VM's (located at /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-virbr0)

I have followed SolusVM's guide here: http://docs.solusvm.com/v2/Default.htm#Installation/Installation.htm and used their quick install. I have followed the guide up until I am told to change the settings for "br0" adapter in their guide, I ran ifconfig and got this as the output:

```
eth0:
  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:76:DF:6A
  inet addr:188.165.203.175  Bcast:188.165.203.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
  inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe76:df6a/64 Scope:Link
  inet6 addr: 2001:41d0:2:94af::/64 Scope:Global
  UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  RX packets:278196 errors:0 dropped:170 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:61666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
  RX bytes:382627105 (364.9 MiB)  TX bytes:7290027 (6.9 MiB)
  Interrupt:16 Memory:fbce0000-fbd00000
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
  inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
  inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
  UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
  RX packets:163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
  RX bytes:27944 (27.2 KiB)  TX bytes:27944 (27.2 KiB)' 

virbr0:
  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:86:8D:B4
  inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
  UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
  RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

So mistake me if I am wrong, but instead of "br0" adapter in their guide, I should be using "virbr0" (that was the first problem) :roll:

Now I have edited the "virbr0" in compliance with their settings, I have added this via vim:

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
BRIDGE=virbr0
HWADDR=00:25:90:76:DF:6A
```

and I have modified eth0 configuration file to read the following:

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=(my mac address)
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=virbr0
```

Now I don't know what I have done, but after entering this into the configuration files (eth0 and virbr0) and restarting the networking by running "/etc/init.d/network restart" in bash, I am disconnected from the SSH terminal I am using which is putty. I know this is normal, but I am unable to connect after, which I should be able to. I have a feeling its something wrong I have entered or not included in the eth0 configuration file which is why I am effectively locked out, and am unable to reconnect to my server without reinstalling the OS via my hosts control panel.

Thank you for reading this and I really appreciate the help!

Comment: It said to use br0 and that's what you were supposed to do. You are specifically _not_ supposed to touch virbr0.

Comment: Oh okay, what is the purpose of virbr0 out of interest? Never knew I wasn't meant to touch it so thank you!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/246343/what-is-the-virbr0-interface-used-for

It sounds to me like it is the bridge that is used for NAT in LXC setups.

Comment: Oh okay, as you can tell I am new to bash (Use to be a Windows man!) I have one more question, under "br0" network adapter, I am instructed to enter an address for a field called "NETWORK" with an address that follows, is that the address for my internal network, and if so is there any way to find it? I have ran ifconfig and it doesn't return a value relating to the "NETWORK" field that I should enter in "br0"